# Python3 permutation based on Tree Structure

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, tree, permutation

I am trying to used the Tree Structure for creating a permutation function:

```
import copy
def myPermutation (newString, newDict):
    if sum(newDict.values()) == 0:
    return ' '
else:
    curDict = copy.deepcopy(newDict)
    nextDict = copy.deepcopy(newDict)
    results = []

    for i in range(len(newString)):
        curChar = newString[i]
        if curDict[curChar] == 0:
            continue
        else:
            print(curDict, ' -> ', curChar)
            nextDict[curChar] -= 1
            print(nextDict)
            for p in myPermutation(newString, nextDict):
                results.append(curChar+p)
            # myPermutation(newString, nextDict)
            # results.append(curChar)
            nextDict=copy.deepcopy(newDict)
    return results

def curDict (newString):
    myDict = dict()
    for char in newString:
        myDict[char] = myDict.get(char,0) + 1
    return myDict

newString = 'ABC'
newDict = curDict(newString)
test = myPermutation(newString, newDict)
print(test)
```

The output is like this:
['ABC ', 'ACB ', 'BAC ', 'BCA ', 'CAB ', 'CBA ']

But if I used 'AAB' as test data my output is:
['AAB ', 'AAB ', 'ABA ', 'ABA ', 'AAB ', 'AAB ', 'ABA ', 'ABA ', 'BAA ', 'BAA ', 'BAA ', 'BAA ']

The whole purpose for using tree structure to do permutation is if one of the char is duplicate, I can avoid overloading recursion function.
[click here for "tree structure algorithm"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrOqD.jpg)

1. Any one has idea for adjusting the code to make the algorithm works?
2. How to avoid using return ' ' in permutation function? According to my output, every permutation element has a **SPACE**. I tried to use '' or None, but the complier always give me error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for **SPACE** issue, I can simply use:

```
for items in test:
print(items.strip(), end=' ')
```

but, is there anyway I can directly do inside permutation function?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out, according to the algorithm, I need convert 'inputString' to a distinct Char String, which **convert 'AAB' to 'AB'**
Then pass the distinct Char String with dict into the permutation function.
Here is the new code:

```
import copy

def myPermutation (newString, newDict):
    if sum(newDict.values()) == 0:
        return ' '
else:
    curDict = copy.deepcopy(newDict)
    nextDict = copy.deepcopy(newDict)
    results = []

    for curChar in newString:
        if curDict[curChar] == 0:
            continue
        else:
            nextDict[curChar] -= 1
            for p in myPermutation(newString, nextDict):
                results.append(curChar+p)
            nextDict=copy.deepcopy(newDict)
    return results

def curDict (newString):
    myDict = dict()
    for char in newString:
        myDict[char] = myDict.get(char,0) + 1
    return myDict

def myDistStr(newDict):
    myStr = ''
    for k, v in newDict.items():
        myStr = k+myStr
    return myStr

newString = 'AABBC'
newDict = curDict(newString)
test = myPermutation(myDistStr(newDict), newDict)
print(len(test))
print(test)
```